how to create glyphs with diacritics using Illustrator and fontforge
I understand you can use Indyfont to create glyphs.
I am trying to do the same using an illustrator template (i found here https://github.com/tomchen/font-template)
I copy a font glyph such as sabon, convert it to outlines and place it on the template. I follow the instructions but when i open it in fontforge i don't see the glyphs i created?
The glyphs i am trying to create are H, D, Z, S with a dot below them.
